# Merging two 3D Meshes

Tags: 3d, mesh, trimesh

I want to know what would be the best way to take two meshes (constructed using trimmesh) and merge them together. The idea would be to identify a face on each mesh and connect the two using those two faces.

Answer (score 3):

Two main approaches:

1. Use a boolean mesh operation: [trimesh docu](https://trimsh.org/trimesh.boolean.html#trimesh.boolean.union) .  But you must have openSCAD or Blender installed for that.

2. Merge the vertices with "brute force": (Have the list of trimesh meshes to merge in "yourList")

   ```
    vertice_list = [mesh.vertices for mesh in yourList]
    faces_list = [mesh.faces for mesh in yourList]
    faces_offset = np.cumsum([v.shape[0] for v in vertice_list])
    faces_offset = np.insert(faces_offset, 0, 0)[:-1]

    vertices = np.vstack(vertice_list)
    faces = np.vstack([face + offset for face, offset in zip(faces_list, faces_offset)])

    merged__meshes = trimesh.Trimesh(vertices, faces)
   ```

Comment: This is same as doing mesh1.union(mesh2, engine = 'scad'). I want to ensure that the meshes connect on specific faces.

Comment: Ok, I was overreading your special requirement. After identifying the two faces, retrieve the 2x3 vertices. With these 6 points, you have all information required to calculate the coordinate transform for mesh2. Make sure that the two faces used for merging are deleted from the merged mesh.

Comment: I think SCAD deletes all the internal faces. But do you know how to compute the required transformations?

Comment: The trimesh library has what you need: [super_imposition_matrix](https://trimsh.org/trimesh.transformations.html?highlight=transformations#trimesh.transformations.superimposition_matrix) and then apply_transform(). The only thing is: Your transform is not unique when using only 3 points (think of an equal sided triangle).